# Jquery find a checkbox inside a table row

Tags: jquery

My html

```
<TR class="datarow" id="rowId"><TD>1</TD><TD>895171</TD><td class="classID"><INPUT type="checkbox" /></TD></TR>
```

how do I use Jquery to find out whether the checkbox in this particular row is checked or not. Assume that i know the unique rowId.

Currently, I am doing this

```
var checkbox = $('#' + rowId + " td input:checkbox");

        if (checkbox.checked) {
           alert("checked");
        } else {
           alert("unchecked");
        }
```

But this doesn't seem to detect when the checkbox is checked.

EDITED
Curiously, the following didn't work either:

```
        var curRow = $('#' + curRowId);
        var checkbox = $(curRow).find('input:checkbox').eq(0);



        if (checkbox.checked) {
           alert("checked");

        } else {
           alert("unchecked");

        }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var isChecked = $("#rowId input:checkbox")[0].checked;
```

That uses a *descendant selector* for the checkbox, then gets the raw DOM element, and looks at its `checked` property.

References for selectors:

- Selectors supported by most browsers: [CSS 2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html)
- Newer selectors supported by some browsers and by various JavaScript libraries (for interacting with the DOM): [CSS3 Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/)

Comment: Er, and the missing reference above: [Additional selectors supported by jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: This is working! Could you provide a solution on how to set it selected if it's not? I can't seem to find it #confused

Comment: @MiguelStevens: Just assign `true` or `false` to the `checked` property.

Comment: @MiguelStevens: "Assignment" is one of the most basic programming operations. `a = b` assigns the value of `b` to `a`. So `$("#rowId input:checkbox")[0].checked = true;` assigns `true` to the `checked` property of the DOM object found via the jQuery expression.

Comment: Thanks! It's just that there's so many ways of assigning things in jQuery :) this one's working!

Comment: @MiguelStevens: Actually, a more jQuery-ish way would use `prop`: `$("#rowId input:checkbox").prop("checked", true);`. That also has the characteristic (advantange or disadvantage, depending on your point of view) that it won't cause an error if the selector didn't find anything.

Answer (score 4):

***Updated:***

```
var rowId = "";
var checked = $("#" + rowId + " input:checkbox")[0].checked;
```

Your original code does not work because you're calling `checked` on a jQuery result set.  You need to get out the actual DOM element, which you can do by calling [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get) (Or by indexing the object directly like in T.J.'s answer).  Since there's only one result, you want the element at index 0 in the result set.

**Edit** after seeing updated code in OP:

Using [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) *reduces the matched elements to the one at the specified index*.  Effectively this will return a jQuery result set with one matched object--the one you requested at the specified index.  It *still* doesn't return a DOM element, which you need to use the `checked` property.

Comment: @Andrew: `get(0)` is a long way 'round too. ;-)

Comment: @gnomixa: The problem is that executing a jQuery selector returns *a set of matched elements*.  Your code will not work because `checked` is not a property or function of the jQuery result set.  You need to pull out the actual DOM element returned by the selector, which you can do by directly indexing the object as shown above. `eq(0)` won't work because it retrieve's a single result in the jQuery result set--but still wrapped in a jQuery object.

Answer (score 2):

If you only have one checkbox per row this is the quickest way

```
!!$('#rowId input:checked').length
```

You can also omit the !! and check against '>0' but I think the !! is actually faster

Answer (score 0):

This would do it

```
var checked = $("#rowId" + rowId + " td.classID input:checkbox").is(":checked");
```