# how to select the checked checkbox rows

Tags: html, checkbox

I have a table form mysql in my html page, and each row has a checkbox, if I checked some checkboxes , how could I output the rows I checked.
now I konw how to output all the rows, but I don't konw how to selected the rows I checked

Comment: do your checkboxes have some unique ids associated with them ?

Comment: can you show in jsfiddle for demo and result

Comment: if you need, then there are

Answer (score 0):

give all the check boxes the same name and assign each one with a different value, say the rows primary key.

Use `request.getParameterValues()` in the servlet and you will get an array which will have only the checked values

Answer (score 0):

Have more you can get checked table rows in javascript. Examples:

```
var allRows = $('#yourTableId tr');
for(var i=0; i<allRows.length; i++) {
   if(allRows[i].find('input:checkbox').checked) {
   //selected row allRows[i]. And you can get value checkbox      allRows[i].find('input:checkbox').value
   }
}
```

or use each loop jquery:

```
$('#yourTableId tr').each(function(index)) {
   if($(this).find('input:checkbox').checked) {
       //selected row $(this). And you can get value checkbox   $(this).find('input:checkbox').value
   }
}
```

And have more answers in stackoverflow for such issues:

[Using jquery to get all checked checkboxes with a certain class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450104/using-jquery-getting-all-checked-checkboxes-with-a-certain-class-name)

[Jquery find a checkbox inside a table row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047153/jquery-find-a-checkbox-inside-a-table-row)

[How to check whether a checkbox is checked in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712/check-checkbox-checked-property-using-jquery)